# Crontab timing sequence expression

Tags: expression, cron

If a job is supposed to be run based on:

```
* */2 * * *
```

When should this job be run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cron job is like the following

```
* */2 * * *
```

It is ***run every minute*** of **every 2nd hour**, every day.

From crontab man page,

```
field         allowed values
-----         --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)

A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for all values from "first-last".
```